# Executing stored procedure(with parameters) using sp_msforeachdb

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm going to get data from multiple databases (on same server) for this I came across a solution of using sp_msforeachdb. Now what I actually want to know about it is how can I pass stored procedure (with some parameters) to it. Here is the chunk of code I've tried on it but I'm in vein to pass parameters. Here my stored procedure has 3 parameters like BookCatId, IsAvailable and BookVersion. I have to pass these three parameters to usp_Get_AllBooks.

Is there any other efficient way to get records from multiple databases via single stored procedure? any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

```
EXECUTE sp_msforeachdb 'USE ?  
IF DB_NAME() NOT IN(''master'',''msdb'',''tempdb'')  
exec usp_Get_All_Books'
```

Comment: So this stored procedure exists in all databases? Are your databases really so dynamic that you need to come up with dynamic code?

Comment: yes, for the purpose to be specific to databases I'll have a databases in string with commas...  like DB_NAME() IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.fnSplitString(''\" + dbSelected + \"'', '', '')). This will exactly go to the mentioned DBs only.

Comment: Using sp_msforeachdb should really be avoided. Build a sql string dynamically and use `exec database.sys.sp_executesql`

Comment: @Stu as I said I've to get data from multiple databases executing only a single stored procedure. If you could explain your proposed ans I can try that too.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way to do this this might help someone, still I'm looking for a quick gentle solution. Any efficient solution will be is most welcome.

```
EXECUTE sp_msforeachdb 'USE ?  
IF DB_NAME() NOT IN(''master'',''msdb'',''tempdb'')  
exec usp_Get_All_Books @BookCatId = ''44'', @IsAvailable = ''1'',@BookVersion= ''2.2'''
```